# Navbar's sticky-top does not work in react.js

Tags: reactjs, navbar, project, react-bootstrap, sticky

My navbar's sticky-top feature doesn't seem to work. However when i click on the links on the navbar it seems to work on each of those pages, but not on the main page alone. This is my App.jsx for the homepage.

```
function App(){
     return (
        <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar/>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<TableComponent />} />
        </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

This is my Navbar component code:

```
function Navbarr() {
  const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(true);
  function toggleCollapse() {
    setCollapsed(!collapsed);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar expand="lg" className="custom-navbar shadow p-3 mb-5 sticky-top">
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand as={Link} to="/">
            DASHBOARD
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" onClick={toggleCollapse}/>
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
            <StyledNav className="me-auto">
              {parts.map((part) => (
                <Nav.Link
                  key={part.key}
                  as={Link}
                  to={`/${part.name.replace(/\s/g, "")}`}
                  component={part.component}
                  style={{ color: collapsed ? 'white' : 'white' }}
                >
                  {part.name}
                </Nav.Link>
              ))}
            </StyledNav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>

      <Routes>
        {parts.map((part) => (
          <Route
            key={part.key}
            path={`/${part.name.replace(/\s/g, "")}`}
            element={<PartComponent component={part.component} {...part.props}/>}
          />
        ))}
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've added sticky-top but it won't seem to work just in my homepage. What can be done? Also, does anyone know how to add more than one component on the homepage? I'm new to react and i dont seem to know what to do.

Comment: Since I read posts bottom to top (*then back to bottom*) the "*I'm new to react and i dont seem to know what to do.*" -> I'd suggest you to read through [https://react.dev/learn](https://react.dev/learn) it's so valuable & I know it will take you some longer time as a beginner but you will understand the **most** about React, and to be honest with you don't beat yourself over the challenges, as they are not really "easy" for beginners I'd suggest you look up at solutions, understand, and the next day try to solve them without looking up at the solutions. You may need to re-visit multiple times

Comment: "Sticky-top doesn't work" part - what doesn't work about it? How do you test it? You'd need to have long enough page so that you can scroll down and see if navbar sticks on top?

Comment: @Aleksandar Thank you so much for your suggestion!! I'll definitely look into it. That was my original plan but i must've gotten impatient, so I ended up posting here. Also, to answer your question, yes, you'd need to have a long enough page and when you scroll down the navbar must stay fixed on the top. However the feature seems to work ONLY on the link-pages present in the navbar, and not the homepage. I figured I would need to modify just my homepage(App.jsx) and not the Navbar.jsx because it clearly works else where. I just needed to know what to change.